# Setting CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES botches check_cxx_source_compiles()

Tags: cmake

Am I missunderstanding the meaning of CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES?

Let's say, for building my project, I want to check that certain library exists, e.g. cstring. So, I check it in CMakeLists.txt:

```
include(CheckCXXSourceCompiles)
set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES cstring)
check_cxx_source_compiles(
        "#include <cstring>
         int main(){ return 0; }"
         HAVE_CSTRING)
```

This check fails as it is. If I take out the line *set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES cstring)*, it passes. As it should, I have the library in the system.

The documentation says CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES: "A list of libraries to add to the link command. These can be the name of system libraries or they can be Imported Targets".
I have read that this list of libraries only affect the check, i.e. check_cxx_source_compiles(). And once set, these are the ONLY libraries that check_cxx_source_compiles() will see.

So, if I wanted to include cstring in the check, wouldn't it make sense that I made available the library for linking? Also, I would be isolating only that library for the check because that is the only one that I care about in this specific case.

How come the check fails if I set CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES?

Comment: `cstring` is not a **library**, which one can **link** with. `cstring` is a C++ **header** file. Specifying a header file in the variable which expects a library has a little sense.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You are right, my bad. I am conflating the library with the header file. I assume the library for cstring is libc.so. If I set CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES to libc.so the check works correctly. Anyway, (from my ignorance) it seems to me that in my sistem (FreeBSD) the compiler (clang-llvm) always link at least these 5 libraries by default: libc++.so, libcxxrt.so, libm.so, libc.so, libgcc_s.so. So apparently, I really don't need to set CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES for any symbol that is in those libraries. Thanks.